# Unable to set NSXMLParser delegate to self

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, debugging, nsxmlparser

I'm trying to create an NSXMLParser and call its delegate methods. On setting the delegate to self (2nd line below) I get a warning `Sending 'XMLParserViewController *' to a parameter of incompatible type 'id <NSXMLParserDelegate>'.` What am I missing here?

```
NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithData:data];
[parser setDelegate:self];
[parser parse];
[parser release];
```

Comment: Does your `XMLParserViewController` class conform to the `NSXMLParserDelegate` protocol (in the interface)?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Change the line: `@interface XMLParserViewController : UIViewController` (in your .h file) to:

```
@interface XMLParserViewController : UIViewController <NSXMLParserDelegate>
```

You forgot to set your UIViewController as a delegate of the delegate (if you will).

Comment: +1 For using correct class name and being slightly quicker than me.

Answer (score 5):

In the declaration of self you should have:

```
@interface YourClass <NSXMLParserDelegate>
```

to let the compiler know that your class conforms to the `NSXMLParserDelegate` protocol.